# css issue when using position fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

trying to resize the `ui-dialog` but when using below css, when i try to resize, it jumps to the top left side

```
$('.ui-dialog').css({   
                width: iLength,
                'top':'50%',
                'left': '50%',
                'position': 'fixed',
                'transform': 'translate3d(-50%,-50%, 0)'
            });
```

any idea what i am doing wrong here

also need to be working when browser is `resized`

i tried with positions relative and absolute but it does not center in any case

Comment: can you please mention the link of snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*.parent {position: relative;}

.child {  position: absolute;  top: 50%;  left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}*

Use this CSS & remove your css.

Comment: where do i add the class parent

Comment: Parent properties are on parent div of "ui-dialog" and child css properties put on "ui-dialog".